# Displaying SQL data in HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql, connectivity

I wrote following code in PHP to get the details from the mysql table but I dont know how to display them in HTML form.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "icsk";
$dbname = "yusuf";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT dsl, Fname, Lname, Cid, pack FROM homereg";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row['dsl']. " " . $row['Fname']. " " . $row['Lname']. " " . $row['cid']. " " . $row['pack'] ."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The above code displays the data on the webpage with the help of echo but i want it to be displayed in form. 
HTML form has following code:

```
<form method="POST" name = "frm" action="homerenew.php">

    <div align="center">
        <table border="1" width="425">
            <tr>
                <td width="223"><font face="Georgia"><b>Subscription Number</b></font></td>
                <td width="186"><input type="text" name="T1" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="223"><font face="Georgia"><b>Your Current Pack</b></font></td>
                <td width="186"><input type="text" name="T2" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="223"><font face="Georgia"><b>Renewal Options</b></font></td>
                <td width="186"><select size="1" name="D1">
                <option value = "1 Month">1 Month</option>
                <option value = "2 Months">6 Months</option>
                <option value = "1 Year>1 Year</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="223"><font face="Georgia"><b>Balance Payable</b></font></td>
                <td width="186"><input type="text" name="T3" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Renew" name="B1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
</form>
```

I am new to PHP connectivity that is why little confused. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You want to paste the php values in HTML Form right??

Comment: you can use php to generate the whole form while you fetch the data from mysql? set the value attribute of the inputs to contain the $row[] ???

Comment: set your values like this `value="<?php echo $row['dsl'];?>"`

Comment: I think you would be better looking for a simple tutorial. This question looks very much like a **do it for me** Here at SO we help you with code you have written that you cannot get quite right, **we do not write your code for you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have .php extension of the page containing your HTML form.

After fetching data from database you could set it into form element like

```
<input type="text" name="T1" size="20" value="<?php echo $row['dsl'];?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using a templating engin similar to PHPTal. You write your html page as an .xhtml file that contains tal: tags that are used by the template engine to insert your php values. [Install instructions](https://phptal.org/manual/en/split/installation.html),  [example of use](https://phptal.org/manual/en/split/firstexample.html).

The benfit of using a template engine is you can remove all html content from your scripts and leave the display logic in the xhtml file. The php code just gathers the data and assigns it to labels your template knows about.

You can get all rows as an array and assign it to a variable name in the template object in php. That variable name is then used in the xhtml file to repeat rows in your table (or any other element).

Php:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPTAL.php';
$rows = getMyDBRows();
// create a new template object
$template = new PHPTAL('my_template_file.xhtml');
$template->rows = $rows;

// execute the template
try {
    echo $template->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Xhtml rows section with example of repeating each row, inserting element contents, setting attributes and using a conditional statement to only display the input field for the row with index 1. Repeat method can be used for options in selects and conditional check for setting selected attribute. Phptal requires strict xhtml structure any errors in your xhtml and the page will return an error identifying where there was a problem.

```
<tr tal:repeat="row rows">
    <td tal:content="row/dsl"><\td>
    <td tal:content="row/fname"><\td>
    <td><input name="lname" tal:attributes="value row/lname, style php: repeat.row.id EQ 1?'display:inline-block':'display:none" tal:content="row/lname"></input>
    ......
<\tr>
```